# Application-defined or object-defined error IF statement

Tags: excel, vba

I get Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error.
it get's stuck on this If statement

```
If Cells(rownumber2, 2).Value <> 1 Then
```

Any help would be appropriated

```
Sub stock()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim rownumber As Long
Dim rownumber2 As Double
Dim rng As Range, i As Range, j As Range, rng2 As Range
rownumber = 0 'Machining 900#
rownumber2 = 1 'maximo 900#
Set rng = Range("j1:j1910")
Set rng2 = Range("A2:A62685")
For Each i In rng
    rownumber = rownumber + 1
    For Each j In rng2
    rownumber2 = rownumber2 + 1
    If i = j Then
        If Cells(rownumber2, 2).Value <> 1 Then
        'If (IsNumber(Search("*Active*", Cells(rownumber2, 2)))) Then
            Cells(rownumber, 10).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
        Exit For
        End If
        Exit For
    End If
 Next
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Why is ```rownumber2``` Double? Couldn't it be just integer?

Comment: So your code worked for me. Is the workbook protected by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

What's the value of rowNumber2 when it fails ?

You never reset its value, so eventually it will exceed the number of rows in a sheet. Maybe you mean to reset it to 2 each time through the "j" loop...

Comment: Looking back that could definitely be the issue not clearing the variable once it leaves the for loop

Answer (score 0):

So I couldn't figure out why that code was not working so I solved the problem by changing the code to this.

```
Sub stock()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim rownumber As Long
Dim rng As Range, i As Range, j As Range, rng2 As Range
rownumber = 0 'Machining 900#
Set rng = Range("j1:j1921")
Set rng2 = Range("A2:A62685")
For Each i In rng
    rownumber = rownumber + 1
    For Each j In rng2
        If i = j Then
            If j.Offset(0, 1) <> "Active" Then
                Cells(rownumber, 10).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                a = j.Offset(0, 1).Value
                i.Offset(0, 1).Value = a
            Exit For
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
     Next
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```